# Script for copying format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a script made by someone else that helps pushing out individual rubrics out to students. 
The script copies the formatting and conditional formatting to my spreadsheet but when I send out to each student, the formatting is no longer there. 
Can someone help me with this?

```
//Copy from teacher spreadsheet to student spreadsheet
var newRange = newSheet.getSheetByName('rubric').getRange("A1:P103");//copies the range over
newRange.setValues(getTabData);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're only setting the values, not the formatting data.

You could use the [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) method on the range to get data and formatting. All it requires is a destination range to insert the data. Without seeing any of your code, it's something like this:

```js
var studentSheet = stuSheet.getRange("A1:P103");
var teacherSheet = newSheet.getSheetByName('rubric').getRange("A1:P103");

teacherSheet.copyTo(studentSheet);
```